# Tomcat deployment using Docker and Kubernetes

Tags: tomcat, docker, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I am very new to kubernetes and how it works but i know it by definition. I want to see how actually it works.
I am quiet good with docker and its functionalities.I have this assignment with me that i want to finish very soon. Could you please guide me as to how shud i go about it step by step.

Create a docker image that runs Tomact. The port it should run is 5000. The tomcat application should run in centos in cluster mode in the docker containers using kubernetes. You can make use any opensource loadbalancers like HAproxy in your solution. Monitoring needs to be set up to make sure the system resources are utilized properly. You can pick your own monitoring solution such as Promethues, Sensu, Nagios, Zabbix, etc. You can attach a dashboard also. The docker containers should store the log file in a permanently in the base machine where docker daemon is running. You are free to use any of the configuration management tool such as SaltStack, Ansible, Puppet, Chef, etc.

I am already done with launching 2 aws ec2 ubuntu instances and installed docker on both the machines. What should i do next?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should start from kuberntes documentation? This one for example - https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/ ;)